# JavaScript lineHeight

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the JS code below to clear the content of a div element to insert some other elements after.However when the div is closed its CSS is pretty much lost and I'm trying to either keep it or renew it:

Javascript code

```
function Changecon() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myList");
    while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }        
    document.getElementById("myList").style.lineHeight="577";
};
```

For some reason last code line won't work.Any solution?Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a div you are talking about?

Comment: If you don't have any content in the element, the line height won't matter. Line-height is the height of the content (usually text) in the element. If you are trying to maintain height I would usually use min-height or height depending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify your line height value, probably with px. Also you could just clear your div using innerHTML.

If you also wanted 577px to be you minimum height when you have no content make sure you set the minHeight of the element. This is because if there are no lines, line height won't affect anything.

```
function Changecon() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myList");

    element.innerHTML = "";
    element.style.lineHeight = "577px";
    element.style.minHeight = "577px";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the unit(`px`) at the end.

```
document.getElementById("myList").style.lineHeight="577px";
```

Comment: Your remove child loop won't work as the variable children is a dynamic nodelist and you are recalculating the length on each loop. This means less than half of the children will actually be removed.

Comment: I know that's how it should work however the lineHeight example at W3School uses it without the (px)unit(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_lineheight.asp).I was a bit confused but finally (px) is obviously needed.

Comment: As for the instertion of new data,could you please tell me the available options?

Comment: @Ronnie147 - What element do you want to insert?

Comment: An image,some tables probably and I'd like them to be included in a div or some divs.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Ronnie147 - [This is how you do it](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/d4orm5ow/).

Comment: That's a lot helpful but it's becoming too long for big webpages.Is there a way to replace raw HTML code with other HTML code using JavaScript?Sorry for being so demanding!

Comment: @Ronnie147 - "_replace raw HTML_" - No, it's not possible. You'll have to remove the elements and append new.

Comment: Will the famous AJAX do that maybe?